# Creating heatmap based on address

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I want to create a heatmap, I have a shapefile of us and geocoded 2000 addresses on it. Now I want to measure density of points and cluster by heatmap. I assume I need a longitude and latitude, but my addresses are based on street, city, state and country. How can I convert to x and y. Do I need to do that?

Comment: You need to Geocode your data.  (there are multiple services for this depends on your area of interest) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding#Example

Comment: I did the geocoding and now I have 2000 points. My problem is now I'm not able to create a heat map in raster like in this link http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html

Comment: Can you describe your issue in more detail please. What is the problem when you try and create your heatmap? I found this tutorial more helpful if you want to take a look at this: <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-zX67ewqC4>

Comment: thanks. well I geocoded about 2000 addresses using mmqgis ( using csv files which contain address of facilities). It generate the points for me. now I want to measure the density of points and hot spot ( clustering). I used this link http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html which exactly what I want. I'm able to do exactly the same up to number 10 when it wanna generate heat map in raster.

Comment: i'm not sure what would be correct row, column and radius for me

Comment: also, I don't know do I need X and Y for my addresses, the sample file had these numbers as well.

Comment: This plugin is a new prototype if you want to try this one out (instructions for download are provided as well):
<https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin>

Comment: Here is another Heatmap tutorial that is almost identical to the one you are looking at. This one might have some more insight to help you out.
<http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/07/tutorial-making-heatmaps-using-qgis-and.html>

The row and column is just meant for pixelsize and the size of the output file, so it is mainly preference. Smaller pixelsize = larger output file, which means the processing will be a bit slower. As long as you input a value for 'Rows' the value for 'Columns' will automatically update.

Comment: You don't need XY coordinates because those should be given once you geocoded your addresses.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to try and make what you are asking much clearer.

Comment: this is how my map look like, when i tried the raster heat map.

Comment: how can i add image here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have longitude and latitude values in respective columns, you can create new columns and use the inbuilt functions. $x for longitude and $y for latitude.
So to do this
open the field calculator

1. create a new column and fill the name for it
2. choose the output field type and width (decimal or otherwise as you want)
3. double click the function you want ie $x for longitude or/and $y for latitude
4. once you have chosen the function, it will appear on the left column and ok button should be highlighted for you to click. Click ok and the column should be created and the values populated.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. well actually it does not allow me to click ok and run it when I chose either x or y.

Comment: i have edited the initial post. check that the layer is in EDIT mode so you can work on it and also you have to double click the function to choose it or type it into the Expression column.